# xrdp service fails to start after reboot

Tags: vnc

The xrdp service is failing after a restart, with the following errors:

```
sudo systemctl restart xrdp.service
Job for xrdp.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status xrdp.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

sudo systemctl status xrdp.service
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-11-30 17:59:31 CET; 2min 55s ago
 Docs: man:xrdp(8)
       man:xrdp.ini(5)
Process: 455 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 440 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 30 17:59:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Nov 30 17:59:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 17:59:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
Nov 30 17:59:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 17:59:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I re-install it, it is working, until the next reboot.
option 1: `sudo apt-get purge xrdp && sudo apt-get install xrdp`
option 2: `sudo apt-get purge xrdp && sudo dpkg -i ./xrdp_0.9.4-1_armhf.deb`

I tried option 2, because I read that there is a problem with xrdp 0.9.1-9, so I downloaded a newer version.

The xrdp-config is unmodified, also it is working fine until reboot. That means I am able to connect to the Pi with no problems. Same with my modified config.

Right now i use this workaround after reboot, but i want to know what exactly causes the error:

```
apt-get purge xrdp --yes && dpkg -i /home/pi/Documents/xrdp_0.9.4-1_armhf.deb
```

Answer (score 6):

Still an issue???

Did you mount /var/log tmpfs???

Seems that xrdp at startup expects a file /var/log/xrdp.log, owner xrdp:adm, access 640 to exist and if not fails

So try:

Disable automatic start at boot time (`systemctl disable xrdp`)

```
touch /var/log/xrdp.log

chown xrdp:adm /var/log/xrdp.log

chmod 640 /var/log/xrdp.log

systemctl start xrdp

systemctl status xrdp
```

You may wish to add this to `/etc/crontab @reboot`

For me it works.

Comment: Thanks; that fixed it for me. (Now I just need to figure out when/why/how it got installed in the first place and if I even need it to auto-run…)

Answer (score 1):

To mkae the service start i've just changed this line in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`:

```
LogFile=/tmp/xrdp.log
```

Comment: If the log file needs to exist, probably best to use /var/tmp which is explicitly supposed to be persistent.

Comment: On Raspbian `/tmp` is persistent, but this is a good point about best practices, since it commonly is not (and really should be cleaned at boot if it isn't).